# How to run a rolling window panel regression?

Tags: r

I have a firm-year panel data consists of 30 years data for 10000 firms:

```
 firm       year        y        x1         x2
 A          1997       150      130        202
 A          1998       200      250        230
 A          1999       350       22         50
 A          2000        30      150         30
 B          1995        50      350         30
 B          1996       350      270         59
 B          1997       789      360        382
 B          1998       360      385         75
 B          1999       362      567        123
```

I want to run a rolling window with width = 6 for a panel regression:

```
plm(y~ lag(x1, 1)+ lag(log(x2), 1), data= dt, 
    model= "within", effect= "twoways",
    index= c("firm", "year"))
```

I think the rolling window should run from year 1 to year 30 10000 times for 10000 firms.
I want to get every coefficient on lag(x1, 1) for each firm-year observation.

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run the code you posted. Take a look at [Ask] to learn how to ask strong questions that get helpful responses

Comment: The `zoo` package has a `rollmean` and a more general `rollapply` function, as well as a `window.zoo`. Not sure how you would use this without a bit more info from your side.